# How to res.sendFile() a file that is in a different directory for Express.js webapp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this inside controllers folder:

```js
//controler.js
exports.serve_sitemap = (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("../../sitemap.xml");
  // or
  // res.send(__dirname + "./sitemap.xml")
  // But neither of these work
};
```

This exported function is imported in a file inside the `routes` directory

```js
const { serve_sitemap } = require('../controllers/indexer')

var router = require('express').Router()

router.get("/sitemap", serve_sitemap)

module.exports = router
```

Currently I am getting a 404 error when I try to get the sitmap at `localhost:3000/sitemap`

**Folder Structure:**
[image: folder structure]

Before, I had the same thing in index.js which is the entry point.

```js
app.get("/sitemap", (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/sitemap.xml");
});
```

This was working perfectly, until I decided to restructure the project

- How can I refer to the sitemap.xml file that is located in the root directory from a file that is in a sub-directory when using res.send()?
- How can I get the absolute path to the root of the project directory, then I can append the file name to the path. This can solve the issse

I maybe missing something obvious. In that case, please help me out.

Any suggestion gratefully accepted. Thanks in advance

Comment: if you `console.log(__dirname)` inside `controller.js` you may be able to figure it out for yourself

Comment: @Bravo `console.log(__dirname)` is giving the absolute path to the dict where the controller.js is located. But that I know. that is what `__dirname` returns

Comment: @Bravo It maybe related to how `res.send()` works.

Comment: why? you're not using res.send

Comment: can it be used to send a file???

Comment: sure, open file, read the file, send the data you read ... but doesn't sendFile do the same in one function? You still have to know where the file is

Comment: I just now tried with `res.send()`. Same outcome

Comment: I think this is a issue faced by many beginners.  So this post should be voted so that others like me can also be benefited from the information in this post

Comment: should I delete it

Comment: here's the thing. The type of beginner that would turn to stackoverflow won't bother searching stackoverflow first, so while this may be useful, it won't be searched for by the people it's most useful for - perhaps it'll be linked to though

Comment: I can understand, and agree with you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think that `res.sendFile(__dirname + "./sitemap.xml")` would work?

First of all `__dirname + "./sitemap.xml"` is not how paths should be concatenated you should use [`join`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathjoinpaths) instead especially if your second path starts with `./`. And there is no file `sitemap.xml` in the directory of the controller:
`__dirname + "./sitemap.xml"` would result in something like `/path/to/project/src/controller/./sitemap.xml`

And why should `"../../sitemap.xml"` work. If you only have `"../../sitemap.xml"` it is relative to the working directory which is the one where (i guess) index.js is located. So `"../../sitemap.xml"` will be resolved based on `/path/to/project`, so `/path/to/project/../../sitemap.xml`.

Due to that is either `res.sendFile("./sitemap.xml")` (relative to `index.js`) or `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../sitemap.xml"))` (relative to the controller).

Comment: Doing `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../sitemap.xml"))` works. Can you explain in your answer what is happening here. According to my little knowledge, `__dirname` gives the absolute path to the dicrectory where the the current file containing `__dirname` is located. andwhat we add to it just gets appended.

Comment: @CuriousLearner What is unclear about that? The documentation says `The path.join() method joins all given path segments together using the platform-specific separator as a delimiter, then normalizes the resulting path.` so you join `/path/to/project/src/controller/` with `../../sitemap.xml` and then this `/path/to/project/src/controller/../../sitemap.xml` is normalized to `/path/to/project/sitemap.xml`